# Unable to insert records to database using PHP (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, registration

I'm trying to insert new records to my database by using the following code.

```
<?php 
session_start();
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog;charset=utf8', 'root', '');

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user,password) VALUES ('$user,$password')");
    $insert->execute();
}
?>
```

And here's the html part.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Register!</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" name="register">
    <label>Registration</label><br>
    <label>New username</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="user"><br>
    <label>New password</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register now!">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Nevertheless the code is not working for some reason and I can't seem to figure out why it won't work.
    Details:

> - My table's name is in fact "users".
> - The name of both fields are correct.
> - I'm able to retrieve data from the database using PDO.
> - I'm also able to login to the database via PDO.
> - The PDO object that connects to the database is    working on the login and the retrieving forms.

Comment: `VALUES ('$user','$password')` you have both values in single quotes,you need single quotes for each.Better yet use prepared statement

Comment: `'$user,$password'` is a single string.

Comment: This question should not be downvoted! What's the matter with you?!

Comment: I didnt downvote it,I usually comment

Comment: Just wow, silliest mistake ever! Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the correct usage of PDO's [Prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) method:

```
$insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user,password) VALUES (:user,:password)");
$insert->execute(array(':user'=>$user, ':password'=>$password));
```